# How to handle inline double quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `a` tag which i generate with JavaScript. I want to manipulate the `href` attribute by giving it a variable. But I have a syntax arror in my HTML, so its not valid.
My first try:

```
'<a href="javascript: file_info(\'' + content_result[i][7] + '\', ' + content_result[i][0] + ')">Edit</a>'
```

And my second one:

```
'<a href=\'javascript: file_info("' + content_result[i][7] + '", ' + content_result[i][0] + ')\'>Edit</a>'
```

As you can see I used backslashes but I every time get an invalid html code.

Comment: Why is the `a` tag also enclosed in quotation marks?

Comment: I think I'll be able to answer this with some clarification: Are you generating HTML in JS to implement later? Is `file_info` a JS function? Or is this _in_ the HTML as itself, and, if so, why is the `a` tag surrounded by quotation marks?

Comment: Should be colsed because I asked a question while it is already clearly answered by my self.

Answer (score 1):

That'd be a great task for template strings, if you could rely on ES6 support.

```
`<a href="javascript: file_info('${content_result[i][7]}','${content_result[i][0]}')">Edit</a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these cases...

I "try" to always use the same "outer" quote.
Let's say, for now, that it's the double ones.

Then I decide if the second level occurs more often than the third.

So second level may be single.
But in your case, the third level occurs more often.

So escape the second level `"`. And use the single-quotes for the third level.

Always try to use "as-less-as-possible" the escaping... Since it makes the code less readeable.

There is no "absolute" way to do it. It depends on your code.

A trick: keep your `+` signs near your vars. For readability.
;)

**So here would be your  line:**

```
"<a href=\"javascript: file_info('" +content_result[i][7]+ "', '" +content_result[i][0]+ "')\">Edit</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'<a href="javascript: file_info(\'' + content_result[i][7] + '\', ' + content_result[i][0] + ')">Edit</a>'
```

My first one works fine. I just had implemented it in a different line for an another element :/

I am very sorry.

Comment: You aswered yourself while people where answering.... But since you question obviously asked for a trick to manage quotes. You could accept my answer.... Or @PA.'s which is good too (but would have been cool with more explanations...).

Comment: I managed it too, and I was looking for a solution to handle my problem. Thats why I asked this question. I just lost the overview on my script thats all. So don't be nasty...

Comment: So you will leave this question unanswered for eternity? Unless your can accept your own answer (I never tryied it) ??

Comment: Nope gonna close it!